# Angular HTML5 mode and ui-router returns 403

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nginx, angular-ui-router

I'm using `ui-router` and HTML mode.

But I'm getting 403 if I reload the page or using the absolute URL.

Here is my Nginx rewrite:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

I've add `.htaccess`:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

But it still not working. My Routes:

```
.config(["$locationProvider", function ($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/dashboard');

        .state('app.dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: '/app/dashboard/dashboard.html',
        })
         .state('app.categories', {
            url: '/categories',
            templateUrl: '/app/category/category.html',
            resolve: {
                loadJs: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                    return $ocLazyLoad.load('/app/category/category.app.js');
                }]
            }
        })
```

I already set `<base href="/">` on my `index.html`

If I'm in dashboard and reload it, it returns me `403 Forbidden`

What am I missing?.

Comment: What's the address after refresh?

Comment: it added extra `/` become `www.example.com/app/dashboard/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your first `location` block like this:

```
location / {
     index index.html;

     # This is done because Angular doesn't perform a page refresh when using
     # HTML5 mode, so all page refresh requests done, the sever render the 'index.html' file
     try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

Comment: works!. i put my `index index.html` outside location / {}. it's just the same right?

Comment: Yes, you can put that also. It's one and the same thing. Nginx will basically inherit from top.